# Getting type/size of `time_t` using ctypes

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes

I'm accessing a C struct which contains some `time_t` fields using python [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module.

Given its non completely portable nature, I cannot define these fields statically as of `c_int` or `c_long` type.

How can I define them to make my code portable?

Example C struct definition:

```
#import <sys/types.h>
#import <time.h>

typedef struct my_struct {
    time_t timestap;
    uint16_t code;      
};
```

Respective python ctypes structure:

```
from ctypes import *

c_time = ? # What do I have to put here?

class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('timestamp', c_time),
        ('code', c_int16),
    ]
```

Comment: Similar question for CFFI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352932/declare-struct-containing-time-t-field-in-python-cffi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is by introspecting the system your script runs on and making a best bet on which integral type to use. Something like,

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    time_t = ctypes.c_uint64
# ...
```

The bottom line is that `time_t` is not defined in the standard. It's up to the OS and compiler. So your definition of `time_t` in your Python script depends on the DLL/so you are interacting with.

Comment: So, basically, two shared libraries loaded into the same binary could have different sizes for a time_t type if they where compiled with different (but compatible) compilers?

Comment: The length of `time_t` would have been determined once the library that uses it has been compiled down to binary. To make the client's source compatible, you just have to use the same settings when compiling the latter.

Comment: It is not enough, though as I'm using a pyrex module in combination with ctypes, I defined a constant holding the result of sizeof(time_t). I cannot guarantee the correct size between the used compiled shared libs, but at least for the compiler settings I currently use (hoping than that the libraries were compiled with the same settings).

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Python 3.12 (still in development at the time of writing this, planned for release in October 2023), [`ctypes.c_time_t`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_time_t) can be used for this, in your example:

```
# This requires Python 3.12, which adds ctypes.c_time_t

from ctypes import *

class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('timestamp', c_time_t),
        ('code', c_int16),
    ]
```

I had a use case for this [last year](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92869) and [the patch](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/92870) was accepted.

If you don't have Python 3.12 yet, something like this could do the trick, although it's not covering all cases (from the PR/issue above):

```
import platform
import ctypes

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    # Assume MSVC(?) - what about mingw/clang?
    time_t = ctypes.c_int64
elif ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p) == ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int64):
    # 64-bit platform of any kind - assume 64-bit time_t(?)
    time_t = ctypes.c_int64
else:
    # assume some kind of 32-bit platform(?)
    time_t = ctypes.c_int32

# ... use time_t here ...
```

This should be fine for Windows (MSVC >= 2005), macOS (x86_64, aarch64) and Linux (arm32, aarch64, x86, x86_64), but might need tweaking for the BSDs on some CPUs.

Once Python 3.12 is released and `ctypes.c_time_t` is a thing, you can just use that.

For example, this is how gPodder's [`libgpod_ctypes.py`](https://github.com/gpodder/gpodder/blob/master/src/gpodder/libgpod_ctypes.py) tries to use `ctypes.c_time_t`, but falls back to some simple heuristics on older systems:

```
# ctypes.c_time_t will be available in Python 3.12 onwards
# See also: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/92870
if hasattr(ctypes, 'c_time_t'):
    time_t = ctypes.c_time_t
else:
    # See also: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92869
    if ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p) == ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int64):
        time_t = ctypes.c_int64
    else:
        # On 32-bit systems, time_t is historically 32-bit, but due to Y2K38
        # there have been efforts to establish 64-bit time_t on 32-bit Linux:
        # https://linux.slashdot.org/story/20/02/15/0247201/linux-is-ready-for-the-end-of-time
        # https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/64_002dbit-time-symbol-handling.html
        time_t = ctypes.c_int32
```

Comment: thanks for getting this merged!  just wanted to get access to a `time_t` value and stumbled on this being added recently