# Declare struct containing time_t field in Python CFFI

Tags: python, c, struct, typedef, python-cffi

I am using CFFI to call a C function from Python that returns a struct. The struct is defined with a `time_t` element. How do I declare the struct to CFFI so that I can access it from Python?

For example, I tried the following (to get the modified time of a file):

```
import cffi
ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef("""
    // From POSIX
    struct timespec {
        time_t tv_sec;
        long tv_nsec;
        ...;
    };
    struct stat {
        struct timespec st_mtim;
        ...;
    };
    // From "man 2 lstat"
    int lstat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
""")
stat = ffi.verify("#include <sys/stat.h>")
```

This gives an error:

```
cffi.api.CDefError: cannot parse "              time_t tv_sec;"                          
:5: before: time_t
```

It does compile after commenting out the line `time_t tv_sec;`, but then of course you can't access the `tv_sec` field. Presumably, CFFI's C parser doesn't support typedefs. You can't just replace `time_t` with the actual type, since the type may be different on different platforms.

Comment: See my very similar answer with working code in [Get file modification time to nanosecond precision][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351867/get-file-modification-time-to-nanosecond-precision

Answer (score 3):

I fear there is no nice answer.  You need to write `typedef long time_t;` or similar, assuming that time_t is always the same size as long.  If the code is supposed to be portable to platforms where time_t might be different, then you would need to separately get the size:

```
ffi1 = cffi.FFI()
ffi1.cdef("""#define SIZE_OF_TIME_T ...""")
lib = ffi1.verify("""
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #define SIZE_OF_TIME_T  sizeof(time_t)
""")
size_of_time_t = lib.SIZE_OF_TIME_T
```

Comment: This has been fixed in a recent version of cffi.  Now you can say ``typedef int... time_t;`` in the cdef(), before using ``time_t``.  It means "time_t is some integer type, please ask the compiler for its size and signedness".